# NLP ML How to know the weight of words used in text classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, text-classification

I am building a tweet classifier where I try to train different ML models to classify tweets from 2 different tweeter accounts. So far I have train Logistic Regression model, K Neighbors Classifier and decision tree classifier.

Is there a way to know what words in the tweets those classifiers used to predict the account? like the weight of words in the classification process?? I am open to train new classifiers that can do that as well.

Already did some ngram analysis on the tweets like word frequency.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question is too broad for StackOverflow. Try to use CrossValidated StackExchange.

Comment: @Tomáš, I suppose it could be read as "how do I compute my own classifier models". But "how do I inspect my trained nltk classifier" is a reasonable question (and would have been even more so if it had named the specific classifier(s) of interest...).

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways, but they depend on the classifier. Since you tagged this `nltk`, I will assume that you are using the nltk's classifiers. Let's say you have trained a `NaiveBayesClassifier` on a classification task. The trained classifier has a method [`most_informative_features()`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier.most_informative_features) that will show you the features (words) with the strongest correlation to some category. You can ask it to show you as many features as you care to.

If memory serves, several nltk classifiers have equivalent methods; but you'll have to look for the ones you use. More generally, you can examine the internal tables of any classifier, and study the code to understand what the numbers mean. (It will help greatly if you understand the algorithm before you look at the code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can give black-box inspector like [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) a try. It explains decision of any classifier on a given example.